# Hibernate - Errors while querying, "loop" of exceptions

Tags: java, hibernate, stack-overflow

I'm writing again because I'm facing another apparently inexplicable problem with **Hibernate**. It all seems to work fine, but when I try to make a simple query it gives me a number of errors (***the list seems to repeat over and over the same exceptions***).

I have a class called **SensoreDB**, which has a composite primary key (I annotated two members with `@Id`, even though this works only with Hibernate) and a static method `getAll()` that should retrieve all the elements in the Database:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sensori")
public class SensoreDB implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="id_sensore")
    private Integer idSensore;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="id_abitazione")
    private AbitazioneDB abitazione;

    @Column(name="soglia_allarme")
    private Float sogliaAllarme;

    @Column(name="tipo_allarme")
    private String tipoAllarme;

    public SensoreDB(){
        super();
    }

    public static List<SensoreDB> getAll(){
        //apro la sessione e la transazione
        SessionFactory sf = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        List<SensoreDB> ret = session.createQuery("from SensoreDB").getResultList();
        session.close();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

For completeness I also show the class (**AbitazioneDB**) which has a one-to-many association with the previous class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="abitazioni")
public class AbitazioneDB {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="indirizzo")
    private String indirizzo;

    @Column(name="nome_proprietario")
    private String nomeProprietario;

    @Column(name="tel_proprietario")
    private String telProprietario;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id_abitazione")
    private Set<SensoreDB> sensori = new HashSet<SensoreDB>();

    public AbitazioneDB(){
        super();
    }
}
```

When I try to simply query the elements that already are in the Database with **TestHibernate**...

```
public class TestHibernate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SensoreDB.getAll();

        System.out.println("Ok!");

    }

}
```

...I get a number of exceptions. It appears that this list is "repeated" continuously in my console:

```
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1218)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1101)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:685)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.resolveEntityKey(EntityReferenceInitializerImpl.java:142)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.resolveEntityKey(AbstractRowReader.java:143)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:94)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.EntityLoadQueryDetails$EntityLoaderRowReader.readRow(EntityLoadQueryDetails.java:241)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:122)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4004)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**[UPDATE]**

I'm sorry, I didn't write the exception because the Eclipse Console didn't show me, now I found out:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`

**[UPDATE 2]**

[Here](http://pastebin.com/cH6earED)'s the complete console output, if it could be helpful.

**[UPDATE 3]**

After hours of trying, I've come to the conclusion that the problem is somewhat related to the use of **fetch type**. Apparently, if I change the annotation in `SensoreDB` from `@ManyToOne` to `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` it all works fine, even though I still have to test it properly. Any idea on why is this happening?

Comment: What is your exception exactly ?

Comment: Hibernate loads a `SensoreDB` then its `AbitazioneDB` then the `SensoreDB`s for each `AbitazioneDB` then the  `AbitazioneDB` of each  `SensoreDB` etc => infinite loop. You can solve the problem by cutting one side of the relationship. For example, remove the `Set<SensoreDB>` in class `AbitazioneDB`.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle that shouldn't be a problem since Hibernate should not do a loop if the corresponding `AbitazioneDB` is already in the session cache and if the data is reasonably structured. But there's another potential problem: Hibernate doesn't know who owns the relation, `AbitazioneDB` or `SensoreDB`? The easiest way would be to add `mappedBy = "abitazione"` to the `@OneToMany` on `sensori` - provided the database structure supports that (and of course the `@JoinColumn` needs to be removed there).

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Thanks for the answer. It seems to work removing that line, but I'm not sure I understood too well. Does this mean that in all kind of relationships I should always cut one side? In the code example I was given all the relationships were on "both sides".

Comment: @Alessandro Cutting one side obviously works but I think that @Thomas is also right : adding `mappedBy` should also work. Nevertheless, I feel that loading automatically a collection is something bad (personal opinion).

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the answer. I just changed the code into:

`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="abitazione")`

But I still get the same errors.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle You're right and later I may consider changing the project, but right now I'd like to understand what's going on and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you remove the join column annotation as well? And could you _please_ also post the exception instead of only the stack trace?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I removed it. Sorry for the exception, I updated the original post.

Comment: @benjamin.d I updated the original post with it.

Comment: @Thomas I think that I found out the source of the problem in Update 3.

Comment: With cyclic/recursice data structures eager fetching can cause Hibernate to try and create huge queries, e.g. in order to join `AbitazioneDB` to `SensoreDB` to `AbitazioneDB` to `SensoreDB` etc. (Hibernate might not break that cycle because it doesn't know where as it doesn't know the data). Lazy fetching breaks that because there is no additional join to load `abitazione` and thus Hibernate will only issue a new query if you try to access the entity. Besides that, the `ToOne` relations have eager fetching by default while the `ToMany` have lazy fetching as their default.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Loops through the references provided on the association annotation so just removing the join column in the ManyToOne side solves the problem.